# Putting values of specific column ranges in other existing columns of the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have received some survey data that, in a simplified manner, looks similar to the following:

```
      Q1 C1 I11 I12 I13     Q2 C2 I21 I22 I23     Q3 C3 I31 I32 I33
0  test1  a   b   c   d  test2  e   f   g   h  test3  i   j   k   l
```

In the end, I have reshaped the data to the preferred structure by executing the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': {0: 'test1'}, 'C1': {0: 'a'}, 'I11': {0: 'b'}, 'I12': {0: 'c'}, 'I13': {0: 'd'}, 'Q2': {0: 'test2'}, 'C2': {0: 'e'}, 'I21': {0: 'f'}, 'I22': {0: 'g'}, 'I23': {0: 'h'}, 'Q3': {
       0: 'test3'}, 'C3': {0: 'i'}, 'I31': {0: 'j'}, 'I32': {0: 'k'}, 'I33': {0: 'l'}})

header_list = ['Q', 'CA', 'IA1', 'IA2', 'IA3']

df1 = df.iloc[:,0:5]
df2 = df.iloc[:,5:10]
df3 = df.iloc[:,10:15]


for x in df1, df2, df3:
    x.columns = header_list

final = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

print(final)
```

Output:

```
       Q CA IA1 IA2 IA3
0  test1  a   b   c   d
0  test2  e   f   g   h
0  test3  i   j   k   l
```

Although this works, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of obtaining an equivalent result (instead of creating subset dataframes as above). Essentially, the values of the columns after the 5th one (i.e. "I13") should be placed under the first 5 accordingly. In this simplified version, this yields 3 rows, since there are only 3 subsets, but this would obviously become more cumbersome with the above code if this becomes larger.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am still new to Python and programming

Answer (score 1):

You can try `reshape`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,5),
             columns=['Q','CA','IA1','IA2','IA3'])
```

Output:

```
       Q CA IA1 IA2 IA3
0  test1  a   b   c   d
1  test2  e   f   g   h
2  test3  i   j   k   l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method if you want to use pandas operations only and don't want to keep changing data types -

```
lst = list(df.columns)
n=5
new_cols = ['Q', 'CA', 'IA1','IA2','IA3']

#break the column list into groups of n = 3 in this case
chunks = [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]

#concatenate the list of dataframes over axis = 0after renaming columns of each 
pd.concat([df[i].set_axis(new_cols, axis=1) for i in chunks], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

```
       Q    CA  IA1 IA2 IA3
0   test1   a   b   c   d
1   test2   e   f   g   h
2   test3   i   j   k   l
```